# How Comparator internally works with ArrayList?(How to trace comparators working w.r.t Arraylist)

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator

can anyone please explain me how comaprator internally works with ArrayList?
My code is working but I am not getting how internally things have been processed.

**program definition:**Sort name in descending order of there score,if two scores are equal then display names in alphabetic order.

```
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.Comparator;
 import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();

    Player[] player = new Player[n];
    Checker1 checker1 = new Checker1();

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        player[i] = new Player(scan.next(), scan.nextInt());
    }
    scan.close();

    Arrays.sort(player, checker1);

    for(int i = 0; i < player.length; i++){
        System.out.printf("%s %s\n", player[i].name, player[i].score);
    }
}
}

class Checker1 implements Comparator<Player> {

@Override
public int compare(Player p1, Player p2) {
    String s1=(String)p1.name;
    String s2=(String)p2.name;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(p1.score+"..."+p2.score);
    if(p1.score>p2.score){
        return -1;
    }

    else if(p1.score==p2.score){
        return s1.compareTo(s2);

    }


    return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: Your `Comparator` is broken for one thing.

Comment: I think the final `return 0;` should be `return 1;`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch..In which scenario?

Comment: Compare(a, b), `returns -1 if a < b; returns 0 if a == b; returns 1 if a > b`.

Comment: You are using an array, not `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to ensure a consistent result when comparing pairs of elements `a, b` and `b, a` the comparison operations need to be consistent, here `if p1.score < p2.score` you return `0`. But, you return `-1` if it is greater. That violates the general contract; Java, in many cases, expects to be able to compare the elements in either order. Better to use [`Integer.compare(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-) and return the result of comparing names only when that is `0`. Like,

```
@Override
public int compare(Player p1, Player p2) {
    System.out.println(p1.score + "..." + p2.score);
    int c = Integer.compare(p1.score, p2.score);
    if (c == 0) {
        return p1.name.compareTo(p2.name);
    }
    return c;
}
```